# What is the Azure App Service naming maximum length?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have been searching at the Microsoft website and other places but it seems it not clearly defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After carefully looking at the [Azure resource naming page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules#microsoftweb), it is not defined as App service but as Microsoft.Web.Site. The naming length is **maximum 60** characters (and minimum 2). This is for the subdomain part only (not including the azurewebsites.net part).